# How can I get the fluxes of fetch_imaging_sample? - astroML

Tags: python, magnitude

I'm working with **astroML** in Python and I need to get the fluxes from the magnitudes in r band of **fetch_imaging_sample()**.

```
from astroML.datasets import fetch_imaging_sample
data = fetch_imaging_sample()
mag = data['rRaw'] # these are the magnitudes in r band
err = data['rErr'] # these are the errors in r band
```

How can I get the fluxes with their errors?

Explain of fetch_imaging_sample: http://www.astroml.org/modules/generated/astroML.datasets.fetch_imaging_sample.html

Comment: `10**(-0.4*mag)` will give you the flux, `err/1.0857` will give the flux error. See e.g. http://slittlefair.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy217/lectures/stats/L18/index.html#magnitudes